# Create lists from lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to write a function which for `n` arguments will create `n` lists and each contains n-th element for every argument, for example:

```
(aux '(1 2) '(3 4)) = `((1 3) (2 4))
```

I wrote such a function:

```
(define (aux . args) 
  (if (null? args) 
      '() 
      (cons (map car args) 
            (aux (map cdr args)))))
```

but when I try to evalute `(aux '(1 2) '(3 4))` the REPL does not show any output.
My question is what should I change because I don't see any syntax errors.

Comment: While it doesn't address the issues in your code, note that this would typically be done with **(map list lists)**.  E.g., **(map list '(1 2) '(3 4))** produces **((1 3) (2 4))**, and **(apply map list '((1 2) (3 4)))** produces the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is correct. In the event you want to use rest arguments and then use it in recursion you should consider wrapping it in a named `let` or make a local helper procedure.

```
(define (zip . args)
  (let aux ((args args))
    (if (ormap null? args) 
        '() 
        (cons (map car args)
              (aux (map cdr args))))))
```

I also do this when there are arguments that don't change. eg. a `map` implementation for only one list I don't pass the procedure at each iteration:

```
(define (map1 proc lst)
  (let aux ((lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (proc (car lst))
              (aux (cdr lst))))))
```

Of course what actually will happen is up to the implementation so don't think of any of these as optimizations. It's mostly for code clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write an `apply` in your function. Don't worry, I make this mistake all the time, which was why I spotted it instantly. ;-)

Basically, you need to use `(apply aux (map cdr args))`. Otherwise, your `aux` is being recursed into with one argument only.

Oh, and you also need to use `(ormap null? args)` instead of just `(null? args)`, since the base case is that all your given lists are exhausted, not that you have no given lists.